# How do I access my Bash History?

Tags: command-line, 11.10, bash, bash-history

I am fairly new to Linux and I need to find a way to show the contents of my Bash History via the command line, and unfortunately I can't seem to find anything that works, or that I can understand. I am using Linux Ubuntu 11.10, and when I open the Bash History manually by finding the file, it opens with something known as gedit.
How will I be able to view the contents of my Bash History via the command line?
Many Thanks!
~ShadedVeil

Comment: `sudo nano ~/.bash_history` this will allow you to open up your `bash_history` and go through it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although, I believe our sudo is passworded as we use Linux on the school system, and the teacher is still finding a way around this. Is there an alternative to using the sudo command?

Comment: Just take off the `sudo` from the command so it would look like this `nano ~/.bash_history`

Comment: You can also search through your history file to find a certain command like this `history | grep ls` which will find all of the times that you have run the command `ls`

Comment: BTW, Why are you using 11.10?  The end-of-life of that version was May 9, 2013.  You really should upgrade to 14.04 or 15.10.

Comment: It's just what's on the School system. I'd assume it's in relation to when the course was made that we are working through. Thanks for the help guys, I will be sure to try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$history
```

and it will show the history

```
 1999  exit
 2000  cd /opt
 2001  sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
 2002  sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar
 2003  mkdir CS-RT-code
 2004  cd CS-RT-code/
 2005  ls -lrt
 2006  history

$ !<history #> to execute the previous history command
```

Answer (score 0):

`less` is a pretty useful command evolved from `more`. You can use it to browse through large text files. Run:

`less $HOME/.bash_history`

Use the Up/Down arrow keys to go up and down in the file. Press `q` to exit.

For more information/keyboard shortcuts in `less`, run `man less`. It will show its manual pages.

For instance, you could also use other utilities, such as `cat` (`cat $HOME/.bash_history`), `more` (`more $HOME/.bash_history`), nano (`nano $HOME/.bash_history`) and Vim (`vim $HOME/.bash_history`).