# Increase reverse-i-search history length

Tags: command-line, search, terminator

Is there a way to increase the default amount of history `reverse-i-search` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) keeps? In Ubuntu 16.04, it doesn't seem to have a very long "memory", sometimes even commands from yesterday are already gone from its history, ie. will not appear even after cycling through all entries with repeated <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

I'm using Terminator as the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the history is specified with the two variables `HISTSIZE` (history of a single terminal session, saved in RAM) and `HISTFILESIZE` (size of the history file, usually `~/.bash_history`). This size is set in number of lines in your `~/.bashrc` file, e.g.:

```bsh
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=10000
```

This saves 1000 lines (= commands) per terminal session and 10000 in the history file.

The reverse-i-search searches the history of the current session as well as the history file, but it can't include commands from other sessions that are still opened.

Further reading:

- [How to change history size for ever?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307541/507051)
- [How do I search my command-line history for commands I used before?](https://askubuntu.com/q/74631/507051)
- [How do I access my Bash History?](https://askubuntu.com/q/732592/507051)

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue and you had the first answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is really easy, just change your `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` variables in you `.bashrc`

```
HISTSIZE=-1
HISTFILESIZE=-1
```

In bash 4.3 and later you can also use HISTSIZE=-1 HISTFILESIZE=-1 to set it to be unlimited.

Consider that `HISTSIZE` is the number of lines or commands that are stored in memory in a history list while your bash session is ongoing.

`HISTFILESIZE` is the number of lines or commands that (a) are allowed in the history file at startup time of a session, and (b) are stored in the history file at the end of your bash session for use in future sessions.

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize)

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

There is no *time* limit but rather a *line* or *size*  limit on the history of the commandline.

You can modify that in your `~/.bashrc`

```
export HISTSIZE=500000
export HISTFILESIZE=500000
```

Would mean a "memory" of 500.000 lines in your history, both currently (`HISTSIZE`) and written to your history file (`HISTFILESIZE`).

However, keep in mind that the file is only written when you *exit* a terminal.

You can `reverse-i-search` your commands *in the same* terminal, before the history is written to the history file, but cannot find your commands in any new terminals before you have not exited the original one!

Comment: ``the file is only written when you exit a terminal.`` Ah, I think that explains it. I generally leave it "running" with the host OS (virtualbox) in hibernation. In my ``.bashrc`` there was HISTSIZE=1000 and HISTFILESIZE=2000 from some team template.

Comment: `history -a` writes it "on demand", if you need it

Comment: There is also a hacky solution to write history **immediately**, with `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"` in the `.bashrc` described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/261411/783023). Although I'm not sure I can recommend that... what I would recommend is setting a `HISTTIMEFORMAT` like this `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='[%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S] '` so you see exactly **when** you executed the command

Comment: update: I've been running this "hacky solution" not for **three years without issues** on multiple devices. So I can definitely recommend this. Its really great to have your history immediately sync up on every command window or ssh session (on the same device)